# BigCommerce - Display buy now button on product page and cart gets automatically empty

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, bigcommerce

Display buy now button on product page which redirects to checkout page. Cart is automatically empty. I Want just that product in the checkout cart on which "Buy Now" button is clicked.

```
function check()
    {
        console.log("hi");
            $( ".dropdown-menu .previewCart .previewCartItem .mini-cart-item-actions .cart-remove" ).each(function() {
              console.log("product-id",$(this).attr('data-cart-itemid'));
               $.ajax({url: "/cart.php?action=remove&item="+$(this).attr('data-cart-itemid'),async: false, success: function(result){
                console.log("success");
              }});
            });
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the URL to remove a product from the cart (`/cart.php?action=remove`), which would explain why the cart is empty. I'd recommend using the Add-to-Cart URLs documented here:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/cart-and-checkout/add-to-cart-url#add-cart-url_add-specific-sku-cart

For example, this URL will add a specific URL to the cart and redirect to the cart page:

`/cart.php?action=add&sku=INSERT-SKU-HERE`

Comment: Hi Karen,
Thanks for your reply.
I want a buy now button on product page and it redirects to checkout page with that product only. if we have firstly added 2-3 products to cart before adding to that specific product from buy now option then we need only that specific product on checkout but now it showing all products to the checkout(including cart products) but i only want that specific product which i clicked on buy now option either we need to hide cart products. From your url product is going to checkout page.

Comment: <div class="form-action">
        <a href="/cart.php?action=add&sku=4015" class="button button--primary" onclick="return check()">
                    Buy Now
                </a>
</div>   

    function check()
    {
        $( ".mini-cart-item .mini-cart-item-actions .link" ).each(function() {
          console.log("product-id",$(this).attr('data-product-id'));
           $.ajax({url: "/cart.php?action=remove&item="+$(this).attr('data-product-id'),async: false, success: function(result){
            console.log("success");
          }});
        });
    }

Please see code